# UITableView - Highlighting Selected Cell [iOS]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios4

I have created a UITableView with customising a TableCell, generally following this tutorial;

http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=353

I have customised it to my needs and it looks fantastic.  However, when I select a row it highlights that row by changing the entire thing blue.  This highlight covers the entire cell and overrides the content, effectively making a big blue box which looks nasty.  I have tried the alternate highlight options of

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

Obviously if selected as gray, the same behaviour happens but with a gray ugly box.  'None' is the desirable option at the minute, but doesn't provide a good experience to my users as i'd like to give some indication that they have selected that row.

Can anyone suggest a way to show that the row is highligted, but still show the text underneath?  Semi opacity?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe it's because your sample code is setting:

`artistLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor clearColor];`.

It will cause the artistLabel's text color become transparent when it's highlighted.

Of cause you can set your own color to your labels' highlightedTextColor property, for example:

`[UIColor whiteColor]`

Comment: What an absolute idiot I am, thank you. Simple answer, that worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this answer is useful, a vote up and select it as correct answer will be very appreciated.

Comment: I always do. I have 100% fore very question I ask. Thanks again.

Comment: :) Thank you, too. It's hard to keep that rate 100%, That's pretty incredible.

Answer (score 8):

*UITableView Cell selected Color*

**Enjoy...**

```
// Image
UIImage *selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"g7.png"];
UIImageView *bgview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:selectionBackground];
cell.selectedBackgroundView=bgview;
[bgview release];
```

or

```
// Color
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
[bgColorView release];
```

Comment: I also would recommend to call [cell setSelectionStyle: UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone] which prevent cell from white rectangle on it perimeter when it is selected.

Answer (score 5):

u can use ur own customization view to selection

here i have green color view.like this u can change whatever customization u want on that.

```
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero 
                                   reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];


    UIView *selectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];

    [selectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionView;


    [selectionView release];

}
```